# Java - Read large .txt data file in batch size of 10

Tags: java, file

I have a large data file say dataset.txt where data is in the format -

```
1683492079 kyra maharashtra 18/04/2017 10:16:17
1644073389 pam delhi 18/04/2017 10:16:17
.......
```

The fields are id, name, state, and timestamp.

I have around 50,000 lines of data in the .txt data file.

My requirement is to read the data from this data file in batch size of 10.

So in first batch I need to read from 0 to 9th elements. Next batch from 10th to 19th elements and so on...

Using BufferedReader I have managed to read the whole file:

```
import java.io.*;
public class ReadDataFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataset.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
        {
           System.out.println(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

But my requirement is to read the file in batch size of 10. I am new to Java so would really appreciate if some one can help me in simple terms.

As per @GhostCat answer - this what I have got -

```
public class ReadDataFile {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataSetExample.txt"));
    readBatch(br,10);       
}

public static void readBatch(BufferedReader reader, int batchSize) throws IOException {
       List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
         String line = reader.readLine();
         if (line != null) {
         // result.add(line);
             System.out.println(line);
        }
      }
     // return result;
       return ;
    }
}
```

The file is read in the readBatch method so how do I know in the main method that the end of file is reached to call the next 10 records? Kindly help.

Comment: In batch of 10 what? Using a BufferedReader, you're already reading in batches of 8192 characters. What you have is just fine. Adding another layer of batching on top of the buffered reader doesn't add anything, and if you want to read 10 lines, then you need to call readLine() 10 times anyway.

Comment: Also, assuming each line, on average, is 40 characters long, your file will be... 2MB large. That's hardly a large file. It could be read completely in memory without any problem.

Comment: @JBNizet My requirement is to read 10 records at one time. If not BufferedReader then what else can I use to read records only in batch size of 10 at one go.

Comment: @JBNizet I am just assuming that the records are 50,000 but it can be a very huge file with billions of records. Requirement is to read only 10 records at a time. Thanks.

Comment: Using BufferedReader is just fine. You just need to read 10 lines instead of all lines, then return, and wait for the next call to the function to read the next 10 lines. All I'm saying is that this requirement doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet how can I achieve this - read 10 lines instead of all lines, then return, and wait for the next call to the function to read the next 10 lines. Please help me with code as I am badly stuck. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your requirements aren't really clear; but something simple to get you started:

A) your main method shouldn't do any reading; it just prepare that BufferedReader object

B) you use that reader with a method like:

```
private static List<String> readBatch(Reader reader, int batchSize) throws IOException {
   List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
     String line = reader.readLine();
     if (line != null) {
      result.add(line);
     } else {
      return result;
     }
  }
  return result;
}
```

To be used in your main:

```
BufferedReader reader = ...
int batchSize = 10;
boolean moreLines = true;
while (moreLines) {
  List<String> batch = readBatch(reader, batchSize);
  ... do something with that list
  if (batch.size() < batchSize) {
    moreLines = false;
}
```

This is meant as "suggestion" how you could approach this. Things missing from my answer: probably you should use a distinct class, and do parsing right there (and return a `List<DataClass>` instead of moving around those raw "line strings".

And of course: 50000 lines isn't really much of data. Unless we are talking an embedded device, there is really not much point regarding "batch style".

And finally: the term **batch** processing has a very distinct meaning; also in Java, and if you intend to go there, see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) for further reading.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the link you shared but I don't batch processing. I need to read data in sizes of 10. First 10 records and then the next 10 and so on. In the function you shared how do I get the batchSize? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Answers are written for a general audience, thus that link. You "set" the batch size by using the second parameter given to that method. And then the batch size manifests itself implicitly by the number of entries that the returned list contains.

Comment: I am not getting it. Please provide some code for sending batch sizes of 10. Thanks.

Comment: My problem is how to call the method again and again. As I am reading the file in the readBatch method that you provided. So from the main method how do I know that the end of the file has been reached. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. Thank you for the help you have provided so far. Looking forward to your enhanced answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Anybody in need of working example ---

```
// Create a method to read lines (using buffreader) and should accept the batchsize as argument 
private static List<String> readBatch(BufferedReader br, int batchSize) throws IOException {
    // Create a List object which will contain your Batch Sized lines
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < batchSize; i++) {  // loop thru all your lines
        String line = br.readLine();
        if (line != null) {
            result.add(line);   // add your lines to your (List) result
        } else {
            return result;  // Return your (List) result
        }
    }
    return result;   // Return your (List) result
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //input file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c://ldap//buffreadstream2.csv"));
    //output file
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c://ldap//buffreadstream3.csv"));
    // Your Batch size i.e. how many lines you want in your batch 
    int batchSize = 5;  // Define your batchsize here
    String line = null;
    long batchNumber = 1;
    try {
        List<String> mylist = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {                  // Do it for your all line in your csv file
            bw.write("Batch Number # " + batchNumber + "\n");
            System.out.println("Batch Number # " + batchNumber);
            bw.write(line + "\n");   // Since br.readLine() reads the next line you have to catch your first line here itself
            System.out.println(line); // else you will miss every batchsize number line
            // process your First Line here...
            mylist = readBatch(br, batchSize); // get/catch your (List) result here as returned from readBatch() method

            for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {   
                System.out.println(mylist.get(i));
                // process your lines here...
                bw.write(mylist.get(i) + "\n");     // write/process your returned lines
            }
            batchNumber++;
        }

        System.out.println("Lines are Successfully copied!");

        br.close();  // one you are done .. dont forget to close/flush
        br = null;   // all 
        bw.flush();  // your
        bw.close();  // BR and 
        bw = null;   // BWs..
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());   // Catch any exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be better to explain how you solved this rather than simply posting code.

Comment: As per bated's comment, edited my response and added the comments to the code.